# Where is the php executable on Debian?

Tags: debian, eclipse, xdebug

Wanting to configure xdebug in eclipse on debian. I can't seem to find the php executable, but var/www processes php in the current version. How can I find the executable to make xdebug work?

Here's my error message:

```
"Failed to launch on php server - Reason: Launch target not found."
```

Comment: /usr/bin as phpPHPVERSION. For example, /usr/bin/php4.

Comment: @subanki - I told eclipse to use usr/bin/php5 but I keep getting the error message "Failed to launch on php server - Reason: Launch target not found." It has me scratching my head.

Comment: try typing "whereis php"..... try typing "updatedb" then afters when done type "locate php"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

type

```
which php
```

one the command line. It should tell you which version is installed. You might want to `ls -l` the result as it will be a symlink. Follow the symlinks until you get the install path.

Comment: Accepting since was first.

Answer (score 1):

try out

```
which php
```

which will "locate a command" (as the manpage tells me).

On a Debian system most commands are symlinks, which point to the real commands. That way you can easily have multiple versions or alternatives of an executable installed with a singe command pointing to the default one (see `man update-alternatives` or this [article about alternatives](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/91).

On my Debian Lenny my php executable can be found at **/usr/bin/php5**.